# Where I can buy a CD for Linux Installation?

Tags: cd

I would like to know where I can buy a CD/DVD for Linux installation on my old computer. Because recently, twice, from eBay I bought a Linux CD installation, but it did not work. While being installed it just stopped working, freeze.

I tried downloading the installation iso file, but it took too long and I had to cancel the download.

I have a very, very old desktop computer with Windows XP installed. Also I cannot afford to buy a new computer.

Comment: even if it slow, try this. It should be faster and it never cancels even if your internet goes off. https://mega.co.nz/#!BI9lCSya!6V8wteT1axxUct97E31TXMMuLIiFUjclwoY7CKWSlu4             Just press download to your computer

Comment: Before you buy anything, maybe give the specs so we know what you mean when you say "I have a very, very old desktop computer".  Depending on specs you may not even be able to run the full Ubuntu.  It could save you some money

Comment: I think his "very, very old desktop computer with Windows XP installed" has maybe 256MB RAM, so Ubuntu is a definite "no" and so is Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase an Ubuntu CD/DVD from http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17